# How to get the earliest unique row based on both date and a condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table which looks like the following,

```
email               tag    updated
email1@domain.com   tag1   2019-10-01
email1@domain.com   tag2   2018-10-01
email2@other.com    tag3   2019-10-01
email2@other.com    tag4   2017-04-01
email3@xyz.com      tag4   2017-11-01
email3@xyz.com      tag1   2019-10-01
email3@xyz.com      tag3   2018-11-08
```

The query needs to do the following:

1. check the earliest tag for each email address.
2. If the earliest tag matches tag1 or tag2, then include it in the results.
3. no duplicate email addresses in the results.

For example, the results of that query on the above dataset would be:

```
email1@domain.com   tag2   2018-10-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `min()` aggregation function

```
 select t1.*, t2.tag from (
  select min(updated) updated, email 
  from tableA 
  where tag in ('tag1', 'tag2')
  group by email) as t1
left join tableA t2 on t2.email = t1.email and t1.updated = t2.updated
```

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=7Mhx6G5UqI)

Comment: This works but I needed to change select max to select min since I wanted the earliest instance.  Thanks

Comment: This will generate _two_ records in the output for `email1@domain.com`.  You should be aggregating only by email.

Comment: [Your query is not working as expected](https://rextester.com/UFKMUW68928).

Answer (score 1):

On MySQL 8+, I would use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY updated) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT email, tag, updated
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1 AND tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2');
```

The CTE assigns a row number to each group of email records, starting with the earliest one.  Then, the subquery finds the earliest records, but only if their tags be `tag1` or `tag2`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.   I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong or not, but I copied your answer, modified the column names and table names and I got an error.  I am using Dbeaver which should be using MySQL 8+.     To be honest, I selected a different answer as correct because I could understand the query based on my limited knowledge of MySQL and the query worked on my first try when I tried it.  I really appreciate your fast response and will try to learn this sometime.

Comment: @bkp The answer you accepted won't generate the output you expect.